# How to Disable delete button from a subform Zoho Creator

Tags: subform, zoho

From default Zoho Creator does not have this issue. To disable this red cross from a subform. Does anyone know if there is any 'hack' deluge script which cancels the on click event of this button?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible, if you embed your form into html page and apply css like this:

```
  #Attendors1-1 a[elname="zc-hideFormFieldEl"]{
    pointer-events: none;
    visibility:hidden;
  }
```

Use Chrome developer tool to find right tags

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to not allow users to delete subform records.

Here is how you do it:

1. Create a workflow for the form that contains the subform
2. Click **Add New Action**
3. Select **Field Actions**
4. Select **Show/Hide subform actions**
5. Select **Hide subform delete entry**
6. And then select the subform field on which this action should be effected

Answer (score 0):

Use field rules it will help u disable delete button:
[image: field rules]

Comment: Please add a more detailed explanation. And maybe you can restrict yourself to using English words. It does not need to be perfect English, but using that kind of extremely shortened non-words gives an impression of lack of respect for this community. A little punctuation would also be a nice touch.